# Tag icon does not appear

Tags: bug, status-completed, sponsored-tags, tag-watching

I'm sure some users have noticed this before, but it seems that nobody complained about it.

When adding a tag on my *Favorite Tags* tab, the icon of the recently added tag isn't being displayed immediately. The page needs to be refreshed.

## Some screenshots

### Before refreshing

[image: Before refreshing]

### After refreshing

[image: After refreshing]

Comment: What is the tag in question?

Comment: @stevvve I added some screenshots.

Comment: @stevvve all sponsored tags. (the bug isn't with the tag itself, just the AJAX code adding it as favorite which doesn't get the icon properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, the client-side part of the update has just manipulated the in-page HTML - it would have no way of knowing about any special UI elements; however, I'm tweaking it so that the ajax call to *save* the preferences also optionally *renders* the element. You'll get an immediate client-side update from the *old* code, then the *actual* UI update when the ajax call completes. From the user's perspective: the icon will appear as the preference saves successfully.

This should be available later today.